# Azure API Management Schema ARM Template import error

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I've got the following schema defined in my ARM template:

```
    {
      "name": "[concat(variables('api-v1-operation-prefix'), '/', variables('schema-v1-report-name'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas",
      "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
      "properties": {
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "document": {
          "value": "[concat('{\r\n  \"', variables('schema-v1-report-name'), '\": {\r\n    \"type\": \"object\",\r\n    \"required\": [\r\n      \"Email\",\r\n      \"LastName\",\r\n      \"Zip\",\r\n      \"Subject\",\r\n      \"Message\",\r\n      \"CategoryId\",\r\n      \"SubcategoryId\",\r\n      \"RequestTypeInt\"\r\n    ],\r\n    \"properties\": {\r\n      \"FirstName\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"LastName\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"Email\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"Phone\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"Zip\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"Subject\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"Message\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"CategoryId\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"SubcategoryId\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"string\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"RequestTypeInt\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"number\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"WantsEmailResponse\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"boolean\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

When I deploy the ARM template the schema doesn't get imported properly and I see the following error in the OpenAPI specification view of the Azure portal:

> x-ms-export-notes:
>     - >-
>       The exported API contains schemas that aren't of content type
>       'application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.swagger.definitions+json', and are hence not
>       exported as Swagger definitions.

Comment: Try to use `"contentType": "application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.swagger.definitions+json"`.

Comment: @JoyWang That gives me the same error, but it adds this error as well but not sure what to make of it:- >-
    Definitions/body parameters are not exported since this API references
    multiple schemas with Swagger definitions as opposed to one. Schemas
    referenced: schema-v1-options,schema-v1-report

Comment: Try to change the `name`, refer to this link: http://mlogdberg.com/

Comment: Interesting, they're not following the format: "document": { "value": "string" } Thanks, I'll give this a try. This also seems to answer the question why the error was saying I had multiple schemas with Swagger definitions, which is how I set it up (as multiple resources).

Comment: If it works, let me know.

Comment: No luck. Here's the ARM template I have for operations and schemas: https://jsonblob.com/0a547583-813f-11e8-adf3-af009eda506f

Comment: There are two ways to pass schema. 1 is to use  document: { "value": "..." } this is intended for non JSON schemas mostly, as we have to provide JSON representation for this endpoint, thus the need to wrap non-JSON data into a JSON string.
For JSON based schemas (like Swagger definitions), you can place them right inside document as a proper json, like:

"document": {
    "definitions": {
        "TYPE-NAME": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
Doing this plus using content-type mentioned above should do it.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin, thanks I tried both ways but got errors. I prefer the 2nd way (json) though. Can you take a look at what I have here? https://jsonblob.com/0a547583-813f-11e8-adf3-af009eda506f I put the json schemas in variables to make browsing the arm template easier (json outline).

Comment: Unless there is something special in ARM template logic, your definitions will not work. this "[variables('schema-v1-options-name')]": "[variables('schema-v1-options')]" defined a property named [variables('schema-v1-options-name')] with a string value of [variables('schema-v1-options')]. Which is not correct. Definition value should be a JSON object, not a string.

Comment: Ok, but the variable is assigned a json value. I was hoping to do it this way, but I'll try it the way you suggest and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the ARM template based on the link from Joy Wang. This got me 90% of the way there. The problem was that for the schemaId of each operation I used the definition name (or type name), but it should be the id for the schema resource.